# How to set maximum number of rows in a flexbox container and hide extra element?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap`.  I'd like to limit the displayed number of items to 2 rows.  Anything after the second row should not show.  Is this possible?

Starter codepen: https://codepen.io/exclipy/pen/qBaZEdV

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

div.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  /* height is determined by font size but is constant for all items*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS grid for this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,100px); /* the width is define here */
  grid-template-rows:auto auto; /* 2 rows */
  grid-auto-rows:0px; /* next rows equal to 0 */
  overflow:hidden; /* hide the overflow */
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

div.item {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px inset black; /* use a shadow instead of border to not increase the height */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If a `grid-gap` is used to add space between the items, the parent container gets sized wrong (it's too tall, in proportion to the grid gap and number of overflowing items). I couldn't figure out a solution. For example see here: https://cdpn.io/e/RwgmbZV